# How to create and use a custom CultureInfo in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I need a method to display a WPF form with non-standard CultureInfo, which is customizable at runtime. E.g. the customer wants to read dates in "de-DE", but currencies in "en-US". The App should be able to display every currency in the world. Dates and Numberformats are almost "en-US" and "de-DE"

I already tried the "CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder", but it requires admin-rights for the application to register the created culture and it will not update the UI if I use the same name for that culture (e.g. "x-myapp-custom")

In "Application.xaml.vb" at startup:

```
Private Sub CreateCustomCulture(thisCultureName As String)
    Dim myCultureBuilder = New CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder(thisCultureName, CultureAndRegionModifiers.Neutral)
    myCultureBuilder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(RegionInfo.CurrentRegion) 'DE
    myCultureBuilder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture) 'de-DE
    Try
        myCultureBuilder.Register()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is working fine, even if it requires to "run as admin" to register the CultureInfo

In "testwindow.xaml.vb":

```
Private Sub Testwindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Me.Language = Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name)
End Sub
```

This is also working fine. 
But when I try to change `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "$"` the setting is stored in the CultureInfo, but not reflected the WPF form. Even if I un- and re-register the CultureInfo and set the WPF language again.

I expect to have my bound Textboxes (`{Binding TestCurrency, ElementName=testwindow, StringFormat=\{0:C2\}}`) to show in "en-US" style (or at least with a dollar-sign), but it keeps showing in "de-DE".

Comment: Hi! I recommend reading https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Jun/14/WPF-Bindings-and-CurrentCulture-Formatting that provides some background information about how to handle CultureInfo in a WPF app. Importantly, culture needs to be set before XAML loads, and any changes made to it thereafter won't be reflected. Do you need to be able to change locale / culture during runtime?

Comment: Hi. Yes, the application must be able to change the currency format at runtime. I'm able so change the language of the form (not the application) at runtime, as long as I change from "de-DE" to "en-EN" (the buildin CultureInfos)